# Zip function not returning expected result in Python?

Tags: python, zip

I have two lists:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = [1]
```

I want my output as:

```
a, 1
b, 1
c, 1
```

Tried doing this:

```
for i, j in zip(a, b):
    print i, j
```

I get only `a, 1`. How can I make it right?

This is my actual scenario:

```
 if request.POST.get('share'):
            choices = request.POST.getlist('choice')
            person = request.POST.getlist('select')
            person = ''.join(person)
            person1 = User.objects.filter(username=person)
            for i, j in izip_longest(choices, person1, fillvalue=person1[-1]):
                start_date = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
                a = Share(users_id=log_id, files_id=i, shared_user_id=j.id, shared_date=start_date)
                a.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/uploaded_files/')
```

Comment: I am not sure what type of object does `User.objects.filter(username=person)` returns, may be it returns an iterator?

Comment: Never mind! Replacing with 0 solved the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably use `itertools.izip_longest()` here:

```
In [155]: a = ['a', 'b', 'c']

In [156]: b = [1]

In [158]: for x,y in izip_longest(a,b,fillvalue=b[-1]):
   .....:     print x,y
   .....:     
a 1
b 1
c 1
```

In case of `zip()` as the length of `b` is just one, so it is going to return only one result.
i.e  it's result length equals `min(len(a),len(b))`

But in case of `izip_longest` the result length is `max(len(a),len(b))`, if `fillvalue` is not provided then it returns None.

Comment: @user1881957 eh! never heard of that error before, you can use b[0].

Answer (score 1):

OK, i'm late by at least one hour, but what about this idea:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = [1]
```

Since the docs on zip state

> The returned list is truncated in length to the length of the shortest argument sequence.

what about turning the list **a** to the shorter argument? And since everything is shorter than a cycle that runs forever, let's try

```
import itertools

d = zip(a, itertools.cycle(b))
```

Thanks to Ashwini Chaudhary for bringing the itertools to my attention ;)